# Annihilator dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I am sitting on a problem. I know that $V$ is a $F$ Vector space and $U$ is a subspace of $V$.
The set $U_0 := \{ f \in V^∗ ~|~ f(u)=0 \; \forall u \in U \}$ is called the Annihilator of $U$.
I should now show that $U_0$ is a subspace of the dual space $V^∗$.
My idea was very simple. Since we know that $U$ is subspace of $V$ we can take two elements $u_1$ and $u_2$ of $U$ and follow by definition of the Annihilator $u_1 + u_2 \Rightarrow f(u_1+\lambda u_2)=f(u_1)+f(\lambda u_2)$ which is a Subdualspace of $f(v)=0$.
Is this okay?

Comment: No, this is not correct. Certainly the equation $f(u_1 + \lambda u_2) = f(u_1) + f(\lambda u_2)$ is true whenever $f \in V^*$, $u_1, u_2 \in U$, and $\lambda \in F$, but this is not what it means for $U_0$ to be a subspace of $V^*$!

Comment: You should begin by writing down the definition of "subspace", and replacing the symbols in that definition by their values in this context. What will it mean for $U_0$ to be a subspace of $V^*$?

Comment: Also, you should use LaTeX to format your post. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a guide.